# Get or answer the call?

Tags: meaning

Is it right to say he did not get my call?
In the meaning of he did not answer my call.
I tried telling sombody that someone did not answer my call.

Comment: I think all are roughly equal, although *get* is more informal.

Answer (score 1):

*He did not answer my call* **is not equal to** *He did not get my call.*

That's because the former one *(didn't answer)* comes from the willingness **OR** some situation where picking up *your* call was not possible such as the receiver was driving a car.

If you want to say that he did not answer your call, your sentence is absolutely fine. `He did not answer my call` and the reason could be anything.

Probably the confusion is the verb *get*. *Get* also means *understanding*. *I did not get this information* means you could not understand it but here, when it's used for *getting a call* it would mean there was some problem and the call did not *reach* to the receiver's phone.

For the medium of electronic communication, *get* would *first* mean *arrival.* We generally ask, *Did you **get** my mail?~ No, I did not.* which means we are asking about the *arrival* of the mail into the receiver's mailbox. To use the verb *get* for *understanding*, I'd prefer telling "*He did not get what I said in my mail."* Because *He did not get my mail* also means he did not receive it.

We do Internet marketing and often provide a package of sending 'bulk SMSes' through the web. Though *receive* might be a proper word, we often ask while testing software, *"Did you get my SMS"*

So, all-in-all, if you want to stay clear, **out of these two,** *he did not answer my call* would be a better phrase over the other sentence.

Comment: I think "Did you get my call?" might also work if you left a message (a voicemail) and you want to know if they've heard it yet, just like your mail example.

Answer (score -1):

**He did not get my call** may mean that there was some network issue and the call didn't reach his phone.

**He did not receive my call** or **He did not attend my call** are two appropriate ways to say what you wanted to say, while **He missed my call** will mean he could not answer it for some reasons.

Comment: "He did not get my call" doesn't mean there was a network issue. We don't why the two didn't speak. He could be screening his calls. He could be eating dinner.

Comment: I changed *would* to *may* for the first sentence. It's absolutely fine now. *"He did not get my call. Why? Maybe, there was some issue with the network though I heard an outgoing ring.* +1